# C# Compare Time between Two Time Intervals

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datetime

Trying to compare  a given Time between two times to see if it's within the those intervals. e.g. if given Time is 00:00 I need to find out if it falls between 21:00:00 to 7:00:00. Tried TimeSpan.Compare no lock and also used > or < for Time Part.

e.g. 
Given Intervals:

> ```
> 7:00:00 to 19:00:00
> 19:00:00 to 21:00:00
> 21:00:00 to 7:00:00
> ```

Times to compare:

> 00:00:00 and 01:00:00

Any help will be appreciated.

**Updated Question:**

Looks like the requirement is quiet vague. The requirement is basically to pass the Time (TimeSpan) and compare with two TimeSpan intervals to see if they fall in to the those interval.

e.g. Lets say employees get different allowances if they work on different time slots below:

> Date Range: 2012-01-01 to 2012-31
>
> ```
> 19:00:00 to 21:00:00 ($10.00)
> 21:00:00 to 7:00:00 ($11.00)
> 7:00:00 to 19:00:00 ($12.00)
> ```

To calculate the hourly rate for an employee I need to check whether the employee has worked

> 1. Between Date Range :2012-01-01 to 2012-31
> 2. Between Time Range above.

And apply $ Rate accordingly.

Comment: Do you need to write a time interval struct? Like a struct containing two time points, namely a start time and an end time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could write youself an extension method like;

```
public static class TimeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsBetween(this DateTime time, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    {
        if (time.TimeOfDay == startTime.TimeOfDay) return true;
        if (time.TimeOfDay == endTime.TimeOfDay) return true;

        if (startTime.TimeOfDay <= endTime.TimeOfDay)
            return (time.TimeOfDay >= startTime.TimeOfDay && time.TimeOfDay <= endTime.TimeOfDay);
        else
            return !(time.TimeOfDay >= endTime.TimeOfDay && time.TimeOfDay <= startTime.TimeOfDay);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't use the DateTime, can only  use Time Part.

Comment: C# has no type for 'time part', so I've just made use of the DateTime struct. The Date part is not used in the extension method. If you are using some other type to describe the Time, then just replace DateTime with 'MyTimeType' and change the comparisons to match.

Comment: Nope it's not returning correct result. This code should return true but it's returning false:
DateTime StartDate = new DateTime(2012, 05, 17, 20, 00, 00);
            DateTime EndDate = new DateTime(2012, 05, 18, 08, 00, 00);            

            DateTime actualStartDate = new DateTime(2012, 05, 17, 00, 00,00,00);

            var result = actualStartDate.IsBetween(StartDate, EndDate);

Comment: Right I see, then you just need some extra conditions in the method to modify the comparison for when EndTime < StartTime.

Comment: Thanks @RJ Lohan, still returns false unfortunately.

Comment: @nilpun - instead of just saying 'it doesn't work' perhaps you need to explain why you think the result is incorrect. Perhaps we don't understand your requirement correctly.

Comment: OK, try now. I tested a few options, and it seems right. However, I think your actual requirement is a bit more complicated than this - what if a person works *across* a time range? (e.g; 06:30 -> 07:30 from your examples)

Comment: Thanks @RJ-Lohan,thanks for your help. I had accept your answer as you were the first to respond my query. Very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The following code...

```
static class DateTimeExt {

    public static bool TimeOfDayIsBetween(this DateTime t, DateTime start, DateTime end) {

        var time_of_day = t.TimeOfDay;
        var start_time_of_day = start.TimeOfDay;
        var end_time_of_day = end.TimeOfDay;

        if (start_time_of_day <= end_time_of_day)
            return start_time_of_day <= time_of_day && time_of_day <= end_time_of_day;

        return start_time_of_day <= time_of_day || time_of_day <= end_time_of_day;

    }

}

class Program {

    static void Test(DateTime t, DateTime start, DateTime end) {
        bool falls_within = t.TimeOfDayIsBetween(start, end);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} \t[{1},\t{2}]:\t{3}", t, start, end, falls_within);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Test(new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0), new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 19, 0, 0));
        Test(new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0), new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 19, 0, 0));

        Test(new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 19, 0, 0), new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 21, 0, 0));
        Test(new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 19, 0, 0), new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 21, 0, 0));

        Test(new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 21, 0, 0), new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0));
        Test(new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 21, 0, 0), new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0));

        Test(new DateTime(2012, 05, 17, 00, 00, 00, 00), new DateTime(2012, 05, 17, 20, 00, 00), new DateTime(2012, 05, 18, 08, 00, 00));
        Test(new DateTime(2012, 05, 17, 09, 00, 00, 00), new DateTime(2012, 05, 17, 20, 00, 00), new DateTime(2012, 05, 18, 08, 00, 00));

        Test(new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));

    }

}
```

...prints the following result:

```
1/1/2012 12:00:00 AM    [1/1/2012 7:00:00 AM,   1/1/2012 7:00:00 PM]:   False
1/1/2012 1:00:00 AM     [1/1/2012 7:00:00 AM,   1/1/2012 7:00:00 PM]:   False
1/1/2012 12:00:00 AM    [1/1/2012 7:00:00 PM,   1/1/2012 9:00:00 PM]:   False
1/1/2012 1:00:00 AM     [1/1/2012 7:00:00 PM,   1/1/2012 9:00:00 PM]:   False
1/1/2012 12:00:00 AM    [1/1/2012 9:00:00 PM,   1/1/2012 7:00:00 AM]:   True
1/1/2012 1:00:00 AM     [1/1/2012 9:00:00 PM,   1/1/2012 7:00:00 AM]:   True
5/17/2012 12:00:00 AM   [5/17/2012 8:00:00 PM,  5/18/2012 8:00:00 AM]:  True
5/17/2012 9:00:00 AM    [5/17/2012 8:00:00 PM,  5/18/2012 8:00:00 AM]:  False
1/1/2012 12:00:00 AM    [1/1/2012 12:00:00 AM,  1/1/2012 12:00:00 AM]:  True
```

Comment: Thanks @branko-dimitrijevic, won't be able to use DateTime start, DateTime end parameters. I can only use TimeSpan as only time interval is provided without date part.

Comment: This test fails:

Test(new DateTime(2012, 05, 17, 09, 00, 00, 00), new DateTime(2012, 05, 17, 20, 00, 00), new DateTime(2012, 05, 18, 08, 00, 00));

Comment: @nilpun How does it fail? It returns `true` as it should. Midnight is between 8 PM and 8 AM.

Comment: @nilpun I don't see how `DateTime` is a problem. What you pass as year, month and day will simply be ignored. It's easy enough to convert from `TimeSpan` as well, if that's your input.

Comment: This looks remarkably similar to what I already posted and I don't see the problem with either...

Comment: @RJLohan You have a slight bug: try passing the same value to all 3 arguments - your method will return `false` and my `true`. Other than that, they should be identical. And yes, I agree - OP should clarify his requirements.

Comment: +1 for pointing that out :-)  easily fixed in the first line, changing < to <=. Though, the answer to the question 'is a point in time between itself' is probably one better answered by Hawking... ;-)

Comment: @branko-dimitrijevic, the  current solution failed because I passed 9AM which doesn't fall between 8:00PM to 8:00AM.

Comment: @nilpun Ahh... I somehow mistook 9 for a 0. You are correct, my solution was incorrect ;) Edited, hopefully fixed - please retest.

Comment: Thanks Branko-Dimitrijevic, although your answer is more detailed and accurate. I had to accept RJLohan's answer as he responded before you.Thanks for your help. I've voted +1 for useful answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Or, if your needs go beyond that, use one of my [favorites libraries](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET).

Comment: thanks but the library doesn't seem to have any function which finds if given time falls under a range of time. Let me know if I'm missing..

Comment: You can use `ITimePeriod.HasInside` or `ITimePeriod.GetRelation` to determine if a time falls into a time-range.

Answer (score 0):

```
var time1 = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
var time2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1.3).TimeOfDay;
var diff = time2 - time1;
```

So this is just for example perposes to show that adding 1.3 days still gives the same time answer.

Comment: No it doesn't... 
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1.3).TimeOfDay);

Prints;
    16:51:54.9517864
    00:03:55.5668215

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why timespan is not working for you.

I tried this sample in my POC application and it worked.

```
 DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime t2 = DateTime.UtcNow;
    t1.TimeOfDay.CompareTo(t2.TimeOfDay);
```

Try this hope it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
string dt=DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
DateTime presenttime=Convert.ToDateTime(dt);

starttime = starttimepicker.ValueString;
DateTime dtime=Convert.ToDateTime(starttime);

if (dtime > presenttime)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Time cannot be greater than System Time. Please Try Again!", "Do not selecting future time", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            starttimepicker.Value = presenttime;
}
```

Comment: oops!! problem in header see whole code below after two tags see  priyank shah's