# Using Time Span to compare two time intervals

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I want to compare between a certain time and the current time to check if it has exceeded a given period.

I think i should be using TimeSpan but i am not sure how. The two dates im comparing are DateTime objects.

```
 TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_timeInterval);

 if(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - rex.LastFired.Ticks > ts.Ticks)
    // bla bla
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Compare Time between Two Time Intervals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631044/c-sharp-compare-time-between-two-time-intervals)

Comment: I cannot see why this is not a real question! Ambiguous, vauge, incomplete ...etc? Leave a comment and ask for explanation as it is almost the case here!

Comment: Take a look here `TimeSpan.Compare Method (TimeSpan, TimeSpan)` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.compare(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

Just compare the difference between your dates with a timespan.

```
var start = new DateTime(2013, 02, 15);
var now = DateTime.Now;

var oneWeek = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0);

if (now - start > oneWeek) {
    Console.Write("One week is passed since start date.");
} else {
    Console.Write("One week not yet passed since start date.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(DateTime.UtcNow - rex.LastFired > ts)
     ...
```

Comment: I think you have to use `rex.LastFired` (without `.Ticks`).

Comment: @AlexFilipovici, yes, that's what I intended to write... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the DateTime.Compare ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx

EDIT: you ll first have to use TimeSpan.Substract or DateTime.Substract, then you can use the appropiate .Compare method.