# C# Test if the actual time is inside a TimeSpan?

Tags: c#, date, testing, intervals

I have two DateTimes and a TimeSpan making the difference between of these DateTimes :

```
TimeSpan Now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
DateTime start= new DateTime(2015, 12, 21);
DateTime end= new DateTime(2016, 1, 1);

TimeSpan interval = end - start;

if(interval.Days == Now)        //<--It doesn't work
{

}
```

How do I test that ?

Comment: `(DateTime.Now - start) <= (end - start)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Time Span to compare two time intervals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022421/using-time-span-to-compare-two-time-intervals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `TimeSpan` for this, it's just a `DateTime` comparison.

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2015, 12, 21);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1);
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

if (now >= start && now <= end)
{
    // now falls within the dates
}
```

I think you may be misunderstanding what it is that `TimeSpan` does.