# C# Check if a minute between two date times

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-comparison

Im struggling to check if there is at least a minute between two date times. I created a game in c# and have limited a part of my game to once a minute every time this command is 
executed it runs a void

The problem is that it does it even if it hasn't been a minute?

```
public void _CheckIfBeenAMinute
{
    string TimeStamp;

    using (IQueryAdapter dbClient = SilverwaveEnvironment.GetDatabaseManager().getQueryreactor())
    {
        dbClient.setQuery("SELECT game_timestamp FROM users WHERE id=" + Session.Id + "");
        TimeStamp = dbClient.getString();
    }

    DateTime TimeStamp_Converted = Convert.ToDateTime(TimeStamp);

    if (TimeStamp_Converted > DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1))
    {
        //It has been a minuted...
        //But the problem is, i it hasnt been it still does this?

        this.SendMessage("You have reached your limit today");
        return;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I have decided to use timespan. But when I try to get the seconds of the timespan after it has reached 60 it resets?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Compare Time between Two Time Intervals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631044/c-sharp-compare-time-between-two-time-intervals)

Comment: what are your values for `TimeStamp_Converted` and `DateTime.UtcNow`

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
if ((DateTime.UtcNow - TimeStamp_Converted).TotalMinutes > 1)
```

Comment: I have changed it to timespan, just removed the timespan from the datetime now? But i have a problem. When doing the .Seconds on the timespan it resets to 0 after a minute? And .TotalMinutes returns a long decimal

Comment: Im sorry but I do not understand what you just commented?

Comment: @AshSmith .Seconds will only return the seconds portion of the time. So if the TimeSpan is a minute and thirty seconds, it will only return 30. TotalMinutes will return that TimeSpan as minutes. A minute and thirty seconds will be 1.5 TotalMinutes

Comment: @AshSmith If you just want the total number of seconds, use `TotalSeconds`

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
if (TimeStamp_Converted < DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1))
```